# How can we open folder as workspace from command line in notepad++?

Tags: command-line, notepad++, command-line-interface

Dragging and dropping opens the folder as workspace, but launching notepad++ from commandline and passing a folder as argument opens all the files int he folder instead of opening as workspace. How can I open a folder as workspace from commandline in notepad++.

I use version 7.2.2

Comment: Click the `?` on the right side of the main menu. The available command line options are shown by choosing the *Command line arguments...* item at the top of that menu.

Comment: It would be ideal if we could write something like:
`notepad++ -lfaws `*`dir-path`* to treat a directory like a "Folder as Workspace".

Answer (score 3):

This feature is now available in **v7.8** [release](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8/)

Here's the [commit](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/commit/57a49c3ba5816f74827784830dbe7c5e494f397c) description which gives an example :

> Add the ability to open folders in "folder as workspace" panel via command line argument "-openFoldersAsWorkspace".
>
> Example:
>
> notepad++ -openFoldersAsWorkspace c:\src\myProj01 c:\src\myProj02
>
> The above command will launch notepad++ with folder as workspace panel by opening myProj01 and myProj02 in panel.